# Python Api C generate memory leak

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have this simple code for run a small `python` code in `C`:

```
Py_Initialize();

string_module = PyUnicode_FromString((char *) "kmer_counter");
module = PyImport_Import(string_module);
function = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, (char *) "counter");
result = PyObject_CallFunction(function, "i", 5);

if ( !result ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Exception:\n");
    PyErr_PrintEx(0);
    exit(1);
}

Py_DECREF(string_module);
Py_DECREF(module);
Py_DECREF(function);
Py_DECREF(result);

Py_Finalize();
```

I test the code with `valgrind` and I have memory leak (here the [output](https://pastebin.com/a6g8AWnv)). After some test I find that the memory leaks are caused by the istruction `Py_Initialize();`. How can I solve this problem?

I run valgrind with this flag:

> valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./exe

Comment: can you check with a more recent version of python (like python 3.7 ?) to see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How can I specify that?

Comment: install a new python version. The output shows you're using 2.7

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I installed python3.7 but if I use this flag -I/usr/include/python3.7 -lpython3.7, it don't find the library

Comment: it's `-lpython37` probably. And `-I` is for compilation includes, link path needs `-L`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I try with your suggestions but this are the error: `ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/include/python3.7'
ld: library not found for -lpython37`

Comment: `-L` needs an _existing_ directory where the _library_ is located, not the includes.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How can I find a valid path of the library for linux and macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you have highlighted is (mostly) not memory leak, but rather
invalid read.  These are very probably caused by the very special way
python manages its memory.

As part of the python source files, you should find a suppression file for valgrind,
that should suppress these messages, as they are not real errors.

For my 3.6.6 python version, it is located in Python-3.6.6/Misc/valgrind-python.supp

So, run your program under valgrind using:
   valgrind --suppressions=path/to/the/python/Misc/valgrind-python.supp

You might also first need to do:
export PYTHONMALLOC=malloc